# Change POJO name while generating from hibernate

Tags: hibernate, naming-conventions, hibernate-mapping, pojo

I'd like to know how i can change the name of my POJO when generating it using hibernate.

My tables have a naming convention of : FR_ and TRN_.
While generating the POJOs I'd like the remove the FR and TRN and append VO to the name.

For example,

**Table name**: FR_ACCOUNT_MST

**POJO to be generated**: accountMstVO

Thanks,
Varun

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right, you have to extend the **DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy** class (hibernate-tool.jar lib) and override **tableToClassName** method.

The code below will rename FR_ACCOUNT_MST to FR_ACCOUNT_MSTVO.

I let you use some regex to get the result wanted.

The variable className contains the package + class name (ie. com.mycompany.project.hibernate.FR_ACCOUNT_MST)

Source: http://www.cereslogic.com/pages/2008/08/05/hibernate-tools-tips-for-reverse/

```
package com.altenor.coffre.generated;

import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy;
import org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.TableIdentifier;

public class CoffreReverseEngineeringStrategy extends DelegatingReverseEngineeringStrategy {

    public CoffreReverseEngineeringStrategy(ReverseEngineeringStrategy delegate) {
        super(delegate);
    }

    //add Base before class name
    public String tableToClassName(TableIdentifier tableIdentifier) {
          String className = super.tableToClassName(tableIdentifier);
          return className+"VO";
        }
}
```

Comment: Damn.. this was the only question that i hadn't marked as answered.. Thanks for the solution.. even though I needed it a few months ago.. :).. and welcome to SOF!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can do it by adding in the **hibernate.reveng.xml** file the name of each pojo:

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
  <table-filter match-schema="CO" match-name="FR_ACCOUNT_MST"/>

  <table name="FR_ACCOUNT_MST" schema="CO" class="com.bonables.co.hibernate.pojo.accountMstVO" />

</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are using Hibernate Tool's ability to reverse engineer the domain model classes from database metadata. In that case, you might want to implement a custom `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.ReverseEngineeringStrategy` as explained [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/hibernatetools/html_single/index.html#custom-reveng-strategy).